# MYSQL: Count Rowid and group by days and counter for previous week.

Tags: mysql

I have an issue where i cannot figure out how to count the number of RowID per day for the previous week, then group by the counter.

[This is my current result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nzx1t.png)

[This is the result i'm trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21H1P.png)

Below is my current query.

```
USE database
SELECT COUNTER AS Counter,
            SUM(CASE WHEN PalletFound = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Total Pallets Found',
            SUM(CASE WHEN PalletnotFound = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Total Pallets Not Found', 
            COUNT(RowID) AS 'Total Counted',
            DATEADD(WK,DATEDIFF(WK,7,GETDATE()),0) AS Mon,
            DATEADD(WK,DATEDIFF(WK,7,GETDATE()),1) AS Tues,
            DATEADD(WK,DATEDIFF(WK,7,GETDATE()),2) AS Wed,
            DATEADD(WK,DATEDIFF(WK,7,GETDATE()),3) AS Thur,
            DATEADD(WK,DATEDIFF(WK,7,GETDATE()),4) AS Fri,
            DATEADD(WK,DATEDIFF(WK,7,GETDATE()),5) AS Sat,
            DATEADD(WK,DATEDIFF(WK,7,GETDATE()),6) AS Sun
       FROM PICounts
       WHERE COUNTER LIKE 'Zoe' OR COUNTER LIKE 'Moe' OR COUNTER LIKE 'Joe'
       GROUP BY Counter
```

Help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Posting the table data and desired result will help us a lot to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Found my own solution. As long as the report is running the same day every week (I.E Monday) the below can be used. This will cover results from Monday - Sunday and the set date can be changed accordingly.

```
USE db
DECLARE @startdate date
DECLARE  @endDate date

SET @startDate = DATEADD(WEEK,-1,GETDATE())
SET @endDate = DATEADD(DAY,-1,GETDATE())

SELECT COUNTER AS Counter,
    @startdate AS 'W/C',
    COUNT(CASE WHEN datepart(dw,Completed)=1 THEN Completed END) as Sun,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN datepart(dw,Completed)=2 THEN Completed END) as Mon,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN datepart(dw,Completed)=3 THEN Completed END) as Tues,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN datepart(dw,Completed)=4 THEN Completed END) as Wed,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN datepart(dw,Completed)=5 THEN Completed END) as Thurs,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN datepart(dw,Completed)=6 THEN Completed END) as Fri,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN datepart(dw,Completed)=0 THEN Completed END) as Sat,
    COUNT(*) AS 'Total Counted',
    SUM(CASE WHEN PalletFound = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Pallets Found',
    SUM(CASE WHEN PalletnotFound = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Pallets Not Found',
    sum(Quantity)-sum(OriginalQuantity) AS 'Units Gained/Lost',
    100-AVG(VARIATIONPCENT) AS 'Accuracy %'    

FROM PICounts

WHERE (COUNTER LIKE 'zoe' OR COUNTER LIKE 'Joe' OR COUNTER LIKE 'Moe') 
AND Completed BETWEEN @startdate AND @endDate

GROUP BY Counter
```

Below are the results I achieved:

```
Counter    W/C        Sun   Mon   Tues    Wed   Thurs  Fri  Sat  TotalCounted   PalletsFound    PalletsNotFound UnitsGained/Lost    Accuracy %
zoe     11/07/2017     0     0    167      0     114    58    0     339               5              20              -923              92.625369
moe     11/07/2017     0     0    0        90    30     30    0     150               1               2              -324              98
joe     11/07/2017     0     0    30       40    30     93    0     193               9              14              -3655             87.4803
```